Clickhouse: do buffer tables have advantage over asynchronous inserts (async_insert) in reading?
Considering delivery velocity in terms of data reading capability buffer tables seems to be a better choice because reading is available as soon as the data is delivered to the buffer

During the read operation, data is read from the buffer and the other table simultaneously.

from here
When for asynchronous inserts the following is valid

Your data is available for read queries once the data is written to a part on storage

from here
So, is there the advantage considering reading?
The comparison here says that asynchronous inserts has only advantages over buffer tables.
The same is mentioned in the note here

A recommended alternative to the Buffer Table Engine is enabling asynchronous inserts.

The same point I get from ClickHouse Docs AI (IDK the quality of the LLM but IMHO this perspective is worth mentioning)

What are the advantages of using Buffer Tables comparing to Asynchronous Data Inserts?


Based on the knowledge sources provided, there are no clear advantages of using Buffer Tables compared to Asynchronous Data Inserts in ClickHouse. In fact, the information suggests that Asynchronous Data Inserts are generally preferred over Buffer Tables.
The Buffer Table Engine documentation explicitly states:
"A recommended alternative to the Buffer Table Engine is enabling asynchronous inserts."
Furthermore, the Asynchronous inserts vs. buffer tables section highlights several advantages of asynchronous inserts over buffer tables, including:
Easier setup and management
No need for explicit DDL changes when target table schema changes
More flexible buffering mechanism with per-query shape and settings buffers
Completely transparent buffering from the client's perspective
The knowledge sources do not provide any specific advantages of Buffer Tables over Asynchronous Data Inserts. It appears that Asynchronous Data Inserts are considered an improvement over the Buffer Table approach for most use cases.
If there were any particular advantages to Buffer Tables, they are not mentioned in the provided knowledge sources. Therefore, based on the available information, I cannot identify any clear advantages of using Buffer Tables compared to Asynchronous Data Inserts in ClickHouse.


no, Buffer tables will full scan for all data which stored in memory, async_insert allow properly apply sparce primary key during reading
